# How to get all column names of a table in in multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, query

I have used the following to just view the column names of a table (without any values) Is there a way to view all column names in one column but separate rows? Maybe do a lateral join? Open for suggestions. It is for exploratory purposes only.

This is what I used so far:

```
select *
from fi.questionnaire
where false;
```

Comment: Tables don't have variables, they have columns

Answer (score 1):

The folling query will provide one column, where each column name of the respective table is displayed in a separate row. The order seems random.

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'questionnaire'
  and table_schema = 'fi';
```

Comment: You can add `order by ordinal_position` to get the correct order